# Entity Framework 7 Disable Proxy Generation for one instance

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have added EF 7 Lazy Loading Proxies to my project, but I have some areas where I do not want proxies to be generated. (Serialisation for transport) My first thought was I could just use `.AsNoTracking()`, to not create proxies, but then they will just raise exceptions when reading an unloaded property.

Is there a way to disable the proxies just for one DataContext instance?

I've found a lot solutions for this for older versions of EF, where you could just set it in the config of the instance like:

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

I've also tried, to register a derived context class, so I get another config region in my startup like so:

```
public class MyNoProxyDataContext : MyDataContext
{
   public MyNoProxyDataContext(DbContextOptions<MyNoProxyDataContext> options) : base(options)
   {
   }
}
```

and in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(c =>
{
   var connection = Configuration.GetSection("Database").GetSection("ConnectionString").Get<string>();
   c.UseSqlServer(connection)
      .UseLazyLoadingProxies();
});
services.AddDbContext<MyNoProxyDataContext>(c =>
{
   var connection = Configuration.GetSection("Database").GetSection("ConnectionString").Get<string>();
   c.UseSqlServer(connection);
});
```

But I cannot create a MyDataContext anymore, because I get an exception, that tells me the options do not fit to my base DataCaontext.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created a factory for my contexts, so I can get a context with a different config where needed.

```
public class MyDataContextFactory
{
    public MyDataContextFactory(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        ContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDataContext>();
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDataContext> ContextOptionsBuilder { get; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public MyDataContext GetDataContext(Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> options = null)
    {
        var connection = Configuration.GetSection("Database").GetSection("ConnectionString").Get<string>();
        ContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
        options?.Invoke(ContextOptionsBuilder);
        return new MyDataContext(ContextOptionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

For anyone who wants to use this approach, keep in mind that this will create new instances of your DbContext every time you use the factory. This is not relevant for me since I only want to read no tracking entities with this.